# Passing data from Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a basic method inside a constructor to calculate the current month of the year and output the value to the HTML . However, I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm new to Angular 2 and TypeScript, so this may just be a silly mistake on my behalf :)

calendar.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class GetMonthsService {
  private GetMonthsRef = this.fbDB.list('xxxx/xxxx/months');
  private GetDaysRef = this.fbDB.list('xxxx/xxxxx/months/Days');
  private currentMonth;

  constructor(private fbDB: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getMonthsList() {
    return this.GetMonthsRef;
  }

  getDaysList() {
    return this.GetDaysRef;
  }

  getCurrentMonth() {
        let currentMonth;
        let d = new Date();
        return this.currentMonth = d.getMonth();
        }

}
```

home.html:

```
<ion-content padding>

    <ion-list-header>
      Current Month Page
    </ion-list-header>

          {{currentMonth}}

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you have a home component as well? Please post =)

Comment: `getCurrentMonth` is weird why not just `return (new Date()).getMonth()`. do you know getMonth return int 0..11?

Comment: We cannot see any method inside the `constructor()`?

Comment: could you post the component detail, where you want to use this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component, where you would like to consume the service and display HTML

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {appService} from '../../providers/app.service';
import {GetMonthsService} from '../../providers/calendar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public appService : appService, public getMonthsService : GetMonthsService) {
    getMonthsService.getCurrentMonth();
  }

}
```

HTML to display the content from the service

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>From calendar service {{getMonthsService.currentMonth}}</h2>

</ion-content>
```

Service class where you want to get the data

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GetMonthsService {

  private currentMonth : any;

  constructor() {}


  getCurrentMonth() {
        let d = new Date();
        this.currentMonth = d.getMonth();
        return this.currentMonth;
        }

}
```

[You can refer here for working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-app-with-provider)

Comment: Thank you very much. Great explanation and a working example. My component was poorly coded that it wasn't calling the service properly.